# I would like to know how to use two variables in a foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, pattern

[image]

In the picture LaTeX does what I want, but only for a little bit. I would like the arrows to go all the way to the middle of the circle but decreasing in length as they go down. Here is my code. I get an error if I try to run it. I can't post the rest of my code as it's part of my thesis and contains sensitive information.

```
\begin{minipage}[h!]{0.8\linewidth}
    \centering
    \hspace*{1cm}\raisebox{-15cm}{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,baseline={(10,-10)},>=stealth]
            \draw (-60pt,0) circle [radius=40pt];
            \draw (-60pt,40pt) -- (-60pt,-40pt);
            %\newcounter{\x}{20pt}
            \foreach \x/\y in {-80/40,-79/38,-78/36,...,-60/0}
            {
                \draw [->,line width=1pt] (-60pt,\y pt) -- (\x pt,\y pt);}
            \foreach \y in {0,-2,-4,...,-40}
            {
                \draw [->,line width=1pt] (-60pt,\y pt) -- (-40pt,\y pt);}
            \draw (60pt,0) circle [radius=40pt];
            \draw (60pt,0) circle [radius=25pt];
            \draw (60pt,40pt) -- (60pt,-40pt);
            \foreach \y in {40,38,36,...,26}
            {
                \draw [->,line width=1pt] (60pt,\y pt) -- (40pt,\y pt);}
            \foreach \y in {-26,-28,-30,...,-40}
            {
                \draw [->,line width=1pt] (60pt,\y pt) -- (80pt,\y pt);}
            %\draw [->,line width=1pt] (-60pt,40pt) -- (-80pt,40pt);
            
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: Use `\foreach \y[count=\x  from -80] in{40,38,...,0} { \draw [->,line width=1pt] (-60pt ,\y pt) -- (\x pt ,\y pt);}` for first `\foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because the repeat syntax `...` is reserved exclusively for the case of looping on a **single variable**. When looping on **two** variables, you have to list **all** the elements on which you want to loop.

I have completely rewritten the code:

- The center of the circle is now the origin point `(0,0)`, which makes it very easy to make a symmetry of center `(0,0)`.
- I loop on only one variable : the other can be easily deduced from the first one.

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,>=stealth,tips=on proper draw]
            \draw (0,0) circle [radius=40pt];
            \draw (0,40pt) -- (0,-40pt);
            \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \y using int(2*\x)]  in {1,...,20}
               { \draw [->,line width=1pt] (0, \y pt) --++ (-\x pt , 0);
                \draw [->,line width=1pt] (0,-\y pt) --++ (\x pt, 0);
                }
                \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```